# Is there anyway to count duplicate strings

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Guys is there a way to count how many times a String occurs in an ArrayList?
So for example if the array consists of the following Strings:

1. "Panadol"
2. "Nurofen"
3. "Nurofen"

How would you get it to do the following:

1. Panadol 1
2. Nurofen 2

Is it possible without using hashmaps? Just using arraylists, while loops, for each loop or if statements?
Any answers are much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you want to use a HashMap? That's like asking how to tighten a screw without a screwdriver.

Comment: Yes! It is possible.

Comment: Sure - dump the data in SQLite table, run a GROUP BY and COUNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a double loop (+ `contains`-check), but it's not effective...

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("Cat");
words.add("Dog");
words.add("Bird");
words.add("Dog");
words.add("Cat");
words.add("Dog");

ArrayList<String> alreadyParsed = new ArrayList<>();
for (String word : words) {
    if (alreadyParsed.contains(word)) {
        continue;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    for (String candidate : words) {
        if (candidate.equals(word)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(word + " " + counter);
    alreadyParsed.add(word);
}
```

Same with `HashMap`:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("Cat");
words.add("Dog");
words.add("Bird");
words.add("Dog");
words.add("Cat");
words.add("Dog");

HashMap<String, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : words) {
    if (counters.containsKey(word)) {
        counters.put(word, counters.get(word) + 1);
    } else {
        counters.put(word, 1);
    }
}

System.out.print(counters);
```